# My program not discovery the functions in struct

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures, compiler-errors

My program not discovery the functions returnTest or others new function that are create in struct Node. The g++ compiler return this error:

```cpp
linkedList.cpp: In instantiation of 'void LinkedList<T>::insert(T) [with T = int]':
linkedList.cpp:37:22:   required from here
linkedList.cpp:31:13: error: 'struct LinkedList<int>::Node' has no member named
'returnTest' std::cout << auxHead->returnTest();
```

My files are:

### Main.cpp

```cpp
#include "linkedList.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

template<class T> LinkedList<T>::LinkedList()
{
    node = NULL;
}

template<class T> LinkedList<T>::~LinkedList()
{
}

template<class T> bool LinkedList<T>::isEmpty(){

}

template<class T> int LinkedList<T>::size(){
    if (node == NULL)
        return 0;
}

template<class T> void LinkedList<T>::insert(T element){
    Node *auxHead = node;

    if (auxHead == NULL){
        Node* newNode = new Node();
        newNode->data = element;
        node = newNode;
    }else{
        std::cout << auxHead->returnTest();
    }
}

int main(){
    LinkedList<int> *newLinked = new LinkedList<int>();
    newLinked->insert(55);
    newLinked->insert(55);
    return 0;
}
```

### LinkedList.hpp

```cpp
#ifndef __LINKEDLIST_H_
#define __LINKEDLIST_H_

#include <stdio.h> 

template <class T> class LinkedList {
    private:
        struct Node {
            T data = NULL;
            Node *next;

            T getData(){
                return data;
            }

            Node getNext(){
                return next;
            }

            int returnTest(){
                return -1;
            }

            T isNIL(){
                return (data == NULL);
            }
        };
        Node *node = NULL;
    public:
        LinkedList();
        ~LinkedList();
        bool isEmpty();
        int size();
        void insert (T&);
};

#endif
```

My g++ version is 4.8.1. Please ignore the method size()

Comment: The implementation of `LinkedList::insert` doesn't match it's declaration in the header. Once I fix that the code compiles, albeit with several warnings. Also, for most practical purposes, class templates need to be implemented in the header, not split between header and cpp file. There are several questions on SO explaining why that's the case.

Comment: This not resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** put to implementation of template class/function. just put the implementation (which is in .cpp) into header file.